# Custom Cells in UITable randomly blank

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a UITable with a custom UITableCell.  When the table displays most of the items are blank except for the disclosure triangle.  As I scroll up and down cells randomly turn on and off, but at any given moment, most are blank.

Additional information:
1) It is the "right cell".  When I click on the disclosure, it goes to the right place.
2) I used the exact same code in another table and it works fine. (Yes, I changed all the variables including the cell identifier.
3) I have disabled reuse of cells, the problem is still there.
4) I have used dummy strings in my cell, the problem is still there
5) The cell is created from a nib.

Here is the code in question (version shown doesn't use reuse cells and has dummy text in variables.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *announcementCellIdentifier = @"AnnouncementCellIdentifier";

NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"AnnouncementCell" owner:self options:nil];
AnnouncementCell *cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
NSArray *keylist = [[NSArray alloc] init];
if ((tableView == self.tableView)) {
    keylist = announcementsInCommunity;
} else {
    keylist = filteredAnnouncementNames;
}

…

cell.announcementCreationTimeLabel.text = @"00/00/00";
cell.announcementCreatorLabel.text = @"The Creator";
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
cell.announcementSubjectLabel.text = @"Subject";

return cell;
```

}

Comment: You are leaking memory on assignment of `keylist`. Do not invoke `alloc/init` on it.

Comment: Thank you for catching that.  I fixed it.  I didn't expect it to solve the underlying bug and it did not.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but normally we can use `owner:nil` when loading nib like this. I still don't see anything other thing that might cause the issue, but it might be in the code section that you omitted as well.

Comment: I changed it with no results.  It seems like maybe the UITable code is having trouble figuring out which cells are visible.  Does that make any sense?

Comment: I also commented out the omitted code.  I am not executing exactly the code shown in the example (with the memory leak fixed)

Answer (score 0):

I decided there had to be something wrong in the nib file, but I couldn't find it.  Finally, I deleted the .xib and started over.  Now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my case, the problem is that the controller have 2 outlets pointing to the same customCell. Don't know how that extra pointer can be an issue.